# Retrieve body of mails with JavaMail Api

Tags: android, list, gmail, jakarta-mail, gmail-imap

I am trying to retrieve the mails body using with JavaMail Api. I can retrieve sentdate, from,, to etc. but I coulnt retrieve the body. The method is turning something like : com.sun.mail.imap ImapMessage @123456 .

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) 
        {
//          list.add(messages[i].getSubject());
//          list.add(String.valueOf(messages[i].getFrom()));
//          list.add(String.valueOf(messages[i].getSentDate()));
            list.add(folder.getMessage(1).toString()); // this line is turning the com.sun.mail....
```

Comment: This [JavaMail FAQ entry](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#mainbody) will help.

Answer (score 0):

This Code is Useful for retrive body part of Mail Using JavaMail API.

```
 Folder inbox = store.getFolder("Inbox");
 inbox.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
 DataHandler dataHandler = message.getDataHandler();
 MimeMultipart mimeMultipart = (MimeMultipart) dataHandler.getContent();
 for (int k = 0; k < mimeMultipart.getCount(); k++) {
   BodyPart bodyPart = mimeMultipart.getBodyPart(k);
 }
```

Comment: it doesnt import to DataHandler?

Comment: I add activation.jar and it allow to use DataHandler but my problem didnt solved:S